# Fixed subplot size, dynamic canvas size

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

The following code creats a plot with two subplots. One plot contains a graph and the other plot a table.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Sample data for the graph
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
n = 10
table_data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(10, n)).round(2)


# Plot the data
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4))

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.table(cellText=table_data, colLabels=['Column {}'.format(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)],
          loc='center', cellLoc='center')
table = ax2.tables[0]
table.auto_set_font_size(False)
table.set_fontsize(12)
table.scale(1, 1.5)
```

In this code the size of the main plot as well as the subplots are fixed. However the number of columns of my data is not fixed. So when a dataset contains more columns I want the plot do be widened by the width of the columns. However the size of the ax1 plot as well as the other columns of the table should stay the same size. So the width of the plot canvas as well as the width of ax2 should be set automatically based on the number of columns I have.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: did you try `(figsize=(n*3, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use `figsize=(n*3,4)`, then it should work (at least for my jupyter notebook, n*3 worked.

Here's the results with `n=5`
[image]

Here's the results with `n=10`
[image]

Here's the results with `n=2`
[image]

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No, not really. The plot on the left varies in width, thats not what I'm looking for. It shall have a fixed size.